# PHP, HTML from <textarea> Принять значение

Tags: php, html

Добрый день. У меня есть такая часть кода:

```
<textarea
    name="cv_info" id="" required
    placeholder="Hello! I’m Robert Smith. Web Developer with over 8 years of experience. Experienced with all stages of the development cycle for dynamic web projects. Having an in-depth knowledge including advanced HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, Angular JS. Strong background in management and leadership."
    cols="60" rows="5">
</textarea>
```

Я пытаюсь принять значение в переменную.

Вот таким образом не получается. Как же его принять? (Работаю с WordPress, пытаюсь записать этот текст в базу данных).

```
$mess = $_POST['cv_info'];
```

Comment: А как в html тег form прописан?

Comment: А вы пишете туда что-нибудь? Или placeholder пытаетесь отправить?

Comment: Ну, я заполняю что-то в textarea, нажимать кнопку отправить ,а как передать мой текст?

Comment: Где эта кнопка отправить и где тег form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="some.php">    
    <textarea name="cv_info" id="" required placeholder="Hello! I’m Robert Smith. Web Developer with over 8 years of experience. Experienced with all stages of the development cycle for dynamic web projects. Having an in-depth knowledge including advanced HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, Angular JS. Strong background in management and leadership." cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
<input type="submit" form="form" value="submit" />

$mess = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cv_info']);
```